# Why my image height is setting wrongly on first load in Firefox?

Tags: css, image

I'm using

From Firebug

```
element {
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
display: block;
z-index: 5;
opacity: 1;
width: 300px;
height: 18px;
 }
```

From Google console:

```
  element.style {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 display: none;
 z-index: 4;
 opacity: 0;
 width: 300px;
 height: 260px;
 }
```

Here is screenshot of problem:

[image]

and here is my code generated by Rails helper:

```
    <img alt="Home_page_4" height="260" src="http://127.0.0.1:3000/assets/home_page_4.jpeg" width="300" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; display: none; z-index: 4; opacity: 0; width: 300px; height: 260px; ">
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please always specify dimensions, instead of `"260"` and `"300"` use `"260px"` and `"300px"`.
And `0` values have to be specified without `px` dimensions. Also, please close `<img/>` tag like this:

```
<img alt="Home_page_4" height="260px" src="http://127.0.0.1:3000/assets/home_page_4.jpeg" width="300px" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; display: none; z-index: 4; opacity: 0; width: 300px; height: 260px; " />
```

Actually, you don't have to use `width` and `height` attributes, they are deprecated. So this markup should work fine:

```
<img alt="Home_page_4" src="http://127.0.0.1:3000/assets/home_page_4.jpeg" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; display: none; z-index: 4; opacity: 0; width: 300px; height: 260px; " />
```

Comment: Apart from the inline style thing :)